# Pyspark : How to select the dataframe with condition

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I have This data frame, I would like to browse the array, when the condition is 1, I stop and take the maximum of value. For exemple, I take the max(16,8)= 8 ;  max(6,10,9,8)=10.

| Identifiant | Value | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 16 | **1** |
| ID2 | 8 | **1** |
| ID3 | 4 | 0 |
| ID4 | 5 | 0 |
| ID5 | 6 | **1** |
| ID6 | 10 | **1** |
| ID7 | 9 | **1** |
| ID8 | 8 | **1** |
| ID9 | 9 | 0 |
| ID10 | 11 | 0 |
| ID11 | 6 | **1** |
| ID12 | 8 | **1** |
| ID13 | 10 | 0 |
| ID13 | 12 | **1** |
| ID14 | 15 | 0 |
| ID15 | 14 | **1** |
| ID16 | 8 | **1** |
| ID17 | 9 | **1** |

we obtain This table :

| Identifiant | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 16 | max(16,8) |
| ID6 | 10 | max(6,10,9,8) |
| ID12 | 8 | max(6,8) |
| ID13 | 12 | max(12) |
| ID15 | 14 | max(14,8,9) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create seperate windows for this. First Create a window to calculate a helper column which assigns each group i.e. 1,1 gets 1, then 0,0 gets 2,then 1,1,1 gets 3 and so on. Once we have that we can use Condition column to filter out zeroes and the get max per partition of the helper column after getting a desending rank to get the max value per group:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w = W.orderBy("Identifiant")
w1 = w.rangeBetween(W.unboundedPreceding,0)
w2 = W.partitionBy("Helper").orderBy(F.desc("Value"))

c = (F.col("Condition")!=F.lag("Condition").over(w)).cast("int")
out = (df.withColumn("Helper",c).fillna({"Helper":0})
         .withColumn("Helper",F.sum("Helper").over(w1)).filter("Condition!=0")
.withColumn("Rnk",F.dense_rank().over(w2)).filter("Rnk==1")
    .drop("Helper","Rnk","Condition")
)
```

---

```
out.show()

+-----------+-----+
|Identifiant|Value|
+-----------+-----+
|        ID1|   16|
|        ID6|   10|
|       ID12|    8|
|       ID13|   12|
|       ID15|   14|
+-----------+-----+
```